# Access the values of the gradient of the cost function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to find the gradient vector of the cost function of my model, a CNN, in respect to the input. I using the Keras (version 2.3.1) backend method `gradients(loss, variables)`, which successfully returns a list of tensors, including the tensor I am interested in at index 0. I need the values of the gradient vector so I can do computations on them, but none of the methods that I have seen described on various other questions work for me.

I first find the gradient and reshape it using the line:

`gradients = tf.reshape(k.gradients(loss, model.input), [784])`

At this point gradients is a tensor of shape (784,) and dtype float, and indexing at 0 gives me a strided_slice tensor with shape () and dtype float. All other answers I have seen have proposed three solutions:

1. Turning the tensor into a numpy array via .numpy, however this returns the error:

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Upon searching for this error I have been told that this happens when eager execution is not on, however I can confirm that it is on for me.

2. Using eval in a session, however when I try to run tensorflow.session, I am met with the error:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'`

InteractiveSession also fails similarly.

3. Using tf.Print like so:

`tf.Print(gradients, gradients, message='Gradients')`

Of course, this does not return the values I am interested in, but it would indicate that they are there. This returns the error:

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Print'`

Does anybody know why these errors occur, even though I appear to satisfy all of the conditions required to use them, or have an alternative method of either returning the values from the tensor or generating the graident of the cost function?

Here are the exact lines that I am running. Note that the loss I am using here is just to check and see if and how the gradient function works, and would be changed later.

```
    outputTensor = model.output
    gradients = tf.reshape(k.gradients(outputTensor, model.input)[0], [784])
    print (tf.executing_eagerly())
    input (gradients)
    input (gradients.numpy())
    tf.Print(gradients, gradients, message='Gradients')
```

Which produces output:

```
True
True
Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(784,), dtype=float32)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Are you using `numpy` or `numpy()`? It's a method, not a property

Comment: I am using it as a method ```input (gradients[0].numpy())``` and receiving ```AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'```

Comment: Just to clarify - you are using eager exec? Trying to reproduce, I got an error message that the gradients()-method is only supported in graph mode, not in eager. Please post a minimal code reproducing the error. Also, for points 2&3: tf.Session is no longer supported in >2.0, and you have a typo in tf.print

Comment: Yes, I am in eager exec. I check this using ```print(tf.executing_eagerly())``` both before and after my call to gradients. I have added a minimal code example.